# get active conversation and attach to it

Tags: xmpp, strophe

So, im building my first strophe chat client. 
i have successfully done a simple client that sends and receives messages. Now i am trying to open a new browserwindow when i receive a message. that new browserwindow will attach to the conversation and continue it

But i cannot for the life of me find out how to properly do this. 
I think the process is like this:
1)get and store jid, rid and sid on connect.
2)When i receive a message i pass jid,rid and sid to single.html
3)Via single.html i attach and try to ontinue or start conversation

But im at a loss. its giving me Invalid SID and ends at that. 
I am truly not even sure this is the right way of doing what i am aiming for.

Heres my connection for single.html (sid, rid and jid are successfully passed with +1 for RID as ive read is crucial)

```
var BOSH_JID = QueryString.boshjid;
var BOSH_SID = QueryString.boshsid;
var BOSH_RID = QueryString.boshrid+1;

function onConnect(status)
{
    if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
    console.log('Strophe is connecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
    console.log('Strophe failed to connect.');
    $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
    console.log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
    console.log('Strophe is disconnected.');
    $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
                console.log("connected to session");

    //log('Strophe is connected.');
connection.send($pres());
connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, "message", null, null, null);
    //connection.disconnect();
    }
}




$(document).ready(function () {
    connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
    connection.rawInput = rawInput;
    connection.rawOutput = rawOutput;
        //connection.connect(jid,password,onConnect);
    connection.attach(BOSH_JID, BOSH_SID, BOSH_RID, onConnect);
        //connection.disconnect();

});
```

Comment: 1. You'll need to add a "Strophe.Status.ATTACHED" to handle the attachment. 2. What's the sid look like and can you verify that it's the same as the original (not getting url encoded)? 3. Would be a good habit to convert your strings to ints (parseInt(QueryString.boshrid)) before doing math.

Comment: Thanks you are absolutely right! im a bit lost in strophe's documentation so status.attached completely went straight passed me. sids are correct, but ive noticed an issue with the jid im passing. I will work on it and additionally casted ints to my numbers =) Thanks for great help.